# popcorn image plugin not working

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, popcornjs

I just can't seem to get popcorn image plugin or any other plugins for that matter to work. And I'm not sure why. Here is the code that's inside file.js.

```
var popcorn = Popcorn( "#video1" )
    popcorn.play()

       popcorn.image({
       start: 5,
       end: 15,
       src: "http://www.usm.edu/news/sites/default/files/Prism%20Concert.jpg",
       target: "image"
       });
```

Here is the code that's inside file.html .

```
<div><video id="video1">
<source src="videos/Makeurbed.mp4" height="400" width="800">
</video></div>
```

Here is the code that links my file.js to my file.html. It's inside the head of my html file.

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://popcornjs.org/code/dist/popcorn-complete.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popcorn-complete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: any errors that you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add that semicolon

```
var popcorn = Popcorn( "#video1" );
popcorn.play();
```

apart from that you also need that div with id `image` as you have mentioned it in target.

add like this:

```
<div><video id="video1" height="400" width="800" controls>
<source src="videos/Makeurbed.mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="image"></div>
```

also remember that the mp4 format is not supported by all browsers and viceversa , it is always better to add more file formats.

like this :

```
<div><video id="video1" height="400" width="800" controls>
<source src="videos/Makeurbed.mp4"></source>
<source src="videos/Makeurbed.ogv"></source>
<source src="videos/Makeurbed.webm"></source>
</video></div>
<div id="image"></div>
```

also add the  **height** and **width** inside the video tag , not inside source tag